# What to use and why?(So and So That)

Tags: grammar

---

> you might run that comb through your hair ***so*** you will look
>   presentable.

---

Why does the writer use ***so***  instead  of ***so that***?

Comment: In a purpose adjunct like this, the subordinator "that" is omissible with no change of meaning. "So" is a connective adverb.

Comment: so that is  commonly used to state a purpose and so is more common as a connector. As stated they both serve the same function in your sentence.